# exjs6 label render value upon databinding

Tags: extjs, data-binding, label

In extjs6 label with databinding, how do I convert the bound value everytime it changes?

Right now I am using a viewmodel with formula, but it only hits this method on creation of the panel, I want it to hit the formula everytime I have an incoming change of the label value.

can someone see what I am doing wrong?

here is my label in view

```
                                    columnWidth: 0.5,
                                xtype: 'label',
                                itemId: 'labelDateStatementId',
                                cls: 'myLabelCRM2',
                                bind: {
                                    text: '{convertDateStatement}'
                                }
```

here is my formula in viewmodel

```
    formulas: {

    convertDateStatement: function (get) {
        var me = this;
        var myView = me.getView();
        var label = myView.queryById('labelDateStatementId');
        debugger;
    }
```

it does hit the formula on view creation... but I need it to change everytime I change the source of the bind value of label.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this solution will be good for You (setting data on view model directly):

Check [example on fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2qmu)

After 2 seconds change label on field.

Or You can bind a record to view model like this:

Check [example 2 on fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2qmv)

Comment: thank you but I did not want to go about adding a timer.  I thought there would be some sort of value formatter no?

Comment: Timeout was just an example of change value in form. How you change the source value? Can you attach the code?

Comment: to use your second example, bind record to view model... in my controller I would need to use the code... setTimeout(function () {
    exampleRecord.set('label', 'new label');
}, 2000);          is that correct?  that it would need to be in my controller?

Comment: No, setTimeout i just used to test record changes.